# Convergence of Poisson random Variable

Tags: statistics, random-variables, weak-convergence, poisson-distribution

Let $X_n \sim Pois(3n^2)$ . Show that $X_n/ n^2$ converges in probability to 3

I got this so far:

$ P(X_n/n^2 = 3) = P(X_n = 3n^2) = \frac{(3n^2)^{(3n^2)}e^{-(3n^2)}}{(3n^2)!}$

$ Lim_{\ \ n->\infty} \frac{(3n^2)^{(3n^2)}e^{-(3n^2)}}{(3n^2)!}$

I'm stuck after this.

Comment: For convergence in probability, you rather need to show that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}P\!\left(\left\lvert\frac{X_n}{n^2}-3\right\rvert>\varepsilon\right)=0$$ for all $\varepsilon>0$.

Comment: You could use Stirling's formula. Another way is to use the weak law of large numbers: one can construct $X_n$ as $X_n:=\sum_{i=1}^{n^2}Y_i$ where $(Y_i)_{i\ge1}$ is a family of independent Poisson$(3)$ r.v.

Comment: @nejimban Im not familiar with this stirling's formula. And as for the other part, how do I proceed from there?

Comment: The WLLN gives that $\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^nY_i$ converges in probability towards $E[Y_1]=3$ as $n\to\infty$. This is also true for $n^2$ in place of $n$.